# C++ override nested class convinces the compiler only partially

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, nested-class

## Preface

*There's an SSCCE linked below.*

I have defined a template class which declares a nested class in my program. The template works for many different datatypes (namely the ones which are overloaded by `std::ostream::operator <<`. I now want to use this template with a type that does not work with it because the type is not overloaded in `std::ostream::operator <<`. I do not want to add another overloaded method.

So this is the basic interface:

```
class Value;

class Datatype {

public:

    virtual std::string to_string(Value* value) = 0;

};

class Value {

    Datatype* m_type;

public:

    Value(Datatype* type) : m_type(type) { }

    std::string to_string() {
        return m_type->to_string(this);
    }

};
```

What the `WrapValueImpl` template class does (see below), is to deliver a `Value` and `Datatype` implementation in one.

```
template <typename T>
class WrapValueImpl : public Value {

    T m_val;

public:

    WrapValueImpl(Datatype* type) : Value(type) { }

    T& get() {
        return m_val;
    }

    static T& get(Value* value) {
        return static_cast<WrapValueImpl*>(value)->get();
    }

    static void set(Value* value, const T& other) {
        get(value) = other;
    }

    class Type : public ::Datatype {

    public:

        virtual std::string to_string(Value* value) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            stream << WrapValueImpl::get(value);
            return stream.str();
        }

    };

};
```

Example usage:

```
typedef WrapValueImpl<int> IntValue;

int main() {
    IntValue::Type t;
    IntValue v(&t);
    IntValue::set(&v, 42);

    std::cout << v.to_string() << "\n"; // prints 42
    return 0;
}
```

All fine so far, this is exactly what I want.

## The Problem

But now, I want to use the `WrapValueImpl` with a typename that is not supported in `std::ostream::operator <<`. Please note again that I do not want to add support for the `<<` operator.

Much rather, I want to overwrite the `Type` class in the `WrapValueImpl` to implement the proper string conversion.

```
typedef std::vector<Value*> ValueArray;
class ArrayValue : public WrapValueImpl<ValueArray> {

public:

    ArrayValue(Datatype* type) : WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>(type) { }

    class Type : public WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>::Type {

    public:

        virtual std::string to_string(Value* value) {
            std::ostringstream stream;
            stream << "[";

            ValueArray& array = ArrayValue::get(value);
            ValueArray::const_iterator it = array.begin();
            for (; it != array.end(); it++) {
                stream << (*it)->to_string() << ", ";   
            }
            stream << "]";
            return stream.str();
        }

    };

};
```

But it doesn't compile at all. The compiler yields errors as if I was using the original `WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>::Type` class instead of the `ArrayValue::Type` class. I did however make tests and inserted prints in `Type::to_string()` and the correct method is called (the method of the overwritten class).

## (SSCCE) But it actually uses the correct `Type` class ...

In the following snippet on Coliru, you can find a full working example of what I am talking about. You can switch the `USE_ARRAY` macro to see the results of using the `ArrayValue` class.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/820e2f2550a8363e

In this example, I also prove that the compiler **actually chooses the correct nested Type class**, yet it complains about the original implementation. Why does it bother when it actually **does not use the type**?

Comment: Please see my updated question, I've added a link to a new snippet which proves that the compiler actually uses the correct nested `Type` class. **Yet it complains** about the implementation of the original class.

Comment: I'm likely missing something basic, but why would you expect `WrapValueImpl` to have any clue at all that `ArrayValue` exposes `Type`, when `WrapValueImpl` itself has no knowledge of the derivation to `ArrayValue` ? In other words, the *original class*, `WrapValueImpl::Type` is the only one it knows anything about, and you've provided no means to change that dynamically that I can see.

Comment: The code will choose the correct Type however the base type from `WrapValueImpl` was already added into existence by the compiler and it's existence is not compatible with std::vector

Comment: You should be specializing `WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>`, not inheriting from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you define `Type` in `ArrayValue` like this `public WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>::Type` then the compiler will instanciate the `Type` from the `WrapValueImpl` impl. `Type` defined in `WrapValueImpl` uses operator << on the templated type T and because he doesn't have operator << for T it will throw errors.

One way to fix this is to use operators for your value type:

```
std::ostringstream& operator << (std::ostringstream& stream,const ValueArray & va);

class ArrayValue : public WrapValueImpl<ValueArray> {

public:

    ArrayValue(Datatype* type) : WrapValueImpl<ValueArray>(type) { }

};

std::ostringstream& operator << (std::ostringstream& stream,const ValueArray & array)
{
    stream << "[";

    ValueArray::const_iterator it = array.begin();
    for (; it != array.end(); it++) {
        stream << (*it)->to_string() << ", ";   
    }
    stream << "]";
    return stream;
};
```

And just don't define the `Type` in your `ArrayValue` class.